# Freemember inline errors are clearing form field values

Tags: freemember

I'm having an issue with freemember inline error checking.  The error checking works fine, but when the page refreshes it loses all the correctly entered data.

So for example if I have a registration page; I fill out my name and other details but miss out a required field like email. When I hit submit the page refreshes and an error message has appeared by the email field, but all the values for name etc are blank and the user has to fill them in again.  Obviously I would prefer those details to have been remembered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a sample of your template code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're hard coding the fields without the values. Have you tried using the example in the [FreeMember docs](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/register_tag.md)?

```
{exp:freemember:register return="account" error_handling="inline" error_delimiters='<span class="error">|</span>'}

    <p>
        <label for="email">Email</label><br />
        {field:email}<br />
        {error:email}
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password">Password</label><br />
        {field:password}<br />
        {error:password}
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="password_confirm">Confirm Password</label><br />
        {field:password_confirm}<br />
        {error:password_confirm}
    </p>

    <p>
        {field:accept_terms} <label for="accept_terms">Accept Terms</label><br />
        {error:accept_terms}
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>

{/exp:freemember:register}
```